# Why did my $2.5 USO1 Call option increase in value today?

Tags: stocks

Today 4/30/20 my seemingly worthless USO call option increased in value.

Specifically: USO1 $2.5 Call 5/8

On 4/29 it was valued at $.04 and stayed there.

4/30 I checked after hours and now it’s up to $.08? Which was wasn’t even the highest it went to today. 
So who is buying this contract? 
Who is allowed to buy this contract? Bc I’m only able to sell and from what I understood, nobody is able to buy it.

I have screenshots and will post if requested. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

On 4/29 USO closed at $18.00 and your call was $0.04

On 4/30 USO closed at $19.12 and your call was $0.08

USO rose $1.12.  What do calls do when the underlying increases in value?  They increase in value.

> So who is buying this contract? Who is allowed to buy this contract? Bc I’m only able to sell and from what I understood, nobody is able to buy it.

Your understanding is incorrect.  If you can buy it then you can sell it.  Suppose I'm the counterparty to your contract.  You're long and I'm short.  What broker would say that you can Sell To Close your long contract but I can't Buy To Close my short contract?  If you do indeed have such a restriction then it's a broker's 'close only' limitation.  Then, my guess would be  that you are using a rinky-dink broker that imposes arbitrary restrictions.  Robinhood?