# why did my $2.5 USO1 Call, increase in value today? 4/30/20

Tags: stocks

I bought a USO call option before the reverse stock split and thought it was worthless because nobody is able to purchase it (nobody wanted to purchase it) but today after hours I checked and it increased a whole 100% in value. How are people able to purchase it? Why would they want to purchase it?

$2.5 USO1 call Exp 5/8
     4/29 = $.04
     4/30 = $.08

[image: USO1 call option]

Comment: "_Why would they want to purchase it?_" Why did _you_ want to purchase it? Presumably, _you_ thought it worth a chance it would make a profit... others presumably think the same.

Comment: Duplicate post of https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/124832/

Comment: Yes I did, but that was before the reverse stock split....also how are people even able to buy this option? bc I can't purchase any more of this contract. When I click on "Trade" my only option is to sell. You can even see the alert there on the page "You can close out your position in this option, but you can't buy additional contracts". I am unable to see the conversion rate as well. As in what will be the price of each option at the new stock price?